# Why does my VBA loop paste incorrect values?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have created a loop where data is copied from a worksheet and pasted into another, however I am having problems with the paste function – sometimes the wrong data gets pasted, seemingly randomly. My current code is:

```
    Sub ACCPR_LOOP()

Dim wsACC_PR As Worksheet
Set wsACC_PR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ACC PR")
Dim wsPR_CALC As Worksheet
Set wsPR_CALC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PR - CALC")
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyCell As Range
Set MyRange = Range("A2:A145")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
Columns("B:C").ClearContents

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    MyCell.Copy
    wsPR_CALC.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wsPR_CALC.Range("B226,B228").Copy
    MyCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Transpose:=True

Next MyCell

End Sub
```

What the code is doing is in Col A are a bunch of dates, it copies the date in A, then pastes it into another worksheet to update a drop-down date selector and change the data. Two of the cells are then copied and pasted back into the original worksheet with an offset of 1 column. For some reason sometimes, the data from the previous date in A is pasted. For example, the date in A17 is copied and pasted into the date selector, the correct data is then pasted into B17, but on the next step, the data relating to A17 is pasted into the next row down at B18.

If a repeat the line:

```
MyCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Transpose:=True
```

the code works but this seems rather inefficient. Any ideas what’s going on in my code and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Set MyRange = Range("A2:A145")` you should declare the corresponding worksheet as well. E.g.:

```
Set MyRange = Worksheets("MyNameIsWhat").Range("A2:A145")
```

Otherwise, it would take the `ActiveWorksheet` and the `MyRange` would be assigned to it.

---

The same goes to `Columns("B:C").ClearContents`.

It should be `Worksheets("TsakaTsakaSlimShaddy").Columns("B:C").ClearConents`

Comment: Loving the Eminem reference, +1 just for that! :)

Comment: "SlimShady" the ranges are not specified to a sheet as discussed above.  Excel is not going to know what you want when you are bringing focus to more than one sheet with a range that is not clearly "pathed".

Answer (score 1):

I always try to avoid the copy/paste function in VBA.  It's processor intensive and functions ... arcanely.

Try this instead:

```
For Each MyCell In MyRange
    wsPR_CALC.Range("A1").Value = MyCell.Value
    Application.Calculate
    MyCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = wsPR_CALC.Range("B226,B228").Value
Next MyCell
```

You'll lose the number formatting, but there are other ways of doing that.
I also added an `Application.Calculate` line, because it looks like you're copying from a formula in the second step, and it's good to make sure that value gets updated.  You can also try `Application.CalculateFull` if plain .Calculate isn't cutting it.

Also, to echo Vit, if you're working with multiple sheets, declaring your sheet as often as possible will help as well.